# My onclicklistener is grayed out and it's not taking me to defined target

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, onclicklistener

My onclicklistener is grayed out and it's not taking me to defined target. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please always show code in text format, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently the part new **View.OnClickListener()** will be marked ***gray*** because the compiler is suggesting a shorthand way of simplifying your code and this is called **lambda**.

So instead of this  **View.OnClickListener()**,
you will now have **v->{}** where **v** is **view** (you can change the latter **v** to any latter of your choice).

To quickly fix this;
Click on the gray part and se ***alt + Enter*** to get suggestion.

**Moreover**,

Setting onClickListener could be in two ways;

1. Implementing onClickListener in your activity.
2. Calling onClickListener directly from your button.

**For the first one;**

Your activity should implement onClickListener;
Then in your onCreate method of your activity, reference the button and set this as context to the button onClick;

```
yourButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
yourButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
yourButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

***button can be more than one.***

--> In your generated onClick method you can now use **switch** statement to check which button is clicked;

**For the second one**
For this make sure you reference your button correctly by importing the corresponding button you used in your xml layout.

**import android.widget.Button**

Reference your button from xml in your activity using **R.id.buttonName**

**Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);**

Now set onClickListener directly to the button;

```
//without lambda
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do whatever you want 

        }
    });


//with lambda
yourButton.setOnClickListener(v->{
//Do whatever here
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried this but not working.  I tried many times , I deleted activity and again tried then also same problem. When I checked logcat it says null pointer exception in java. please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Check your activity setContentView and make sure it is pointing to your xml layout where you have your button; Lets say your Layout is "layout.xml", In the onCreate method of your activity; set contentView to that particular layout where you have referenced the button.

Comment: If you still facing the problem.... upload image of your project so that we can help you better.

Comment: Ok sir I will check it.Thanks a lot sir . If any I will upload the project XML with java.

Comment: Welcome Kanzal Haq A

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the graying out - this is Studio's way of telling you this bit of code is unnecessary and can be replaced with a shorter code.

If you hover the mouse cursor on the grayed-out area you will see the Studio suggests that you use a [Lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp) instead.

[image]

[Lambdas](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp) are just a shorthand way of writing methods. For example, Lambda version of onClickListener translates to this code.

[image]

You can either choose to ***go with the lambda suggestion*** or ***leave the code as-is*** - either way the code will run.